# What is OLDPWD in phpinfo after installing Xdebug?

Tags: php, linux, xdebug, selinux

I noticed that this line...

```
OLDPWD  /webroot/shareddev/xdebug/xdebug-2.1.1/xdebug-2.1.1
```

...appeared or was modified after I compiled xdebug.so using the instructions given in: http://www.xdebug.org/find-binary.php

I don't have the Xdebug extension running anymore, so I wonder how to get it back to its original state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of [`OLDPWD`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#OLDPWD) is the **old** [(**p**rint) **w**orking **d**irectory](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PWDREF) as set by the cd command.

Comment: I think that php logs from where you started the php server and stores the current location and another location where you also started a server. If you ever start from one location, oldpwd should be empty.